# Symfony: strange function behaviour, serialization

Tags: php, symfony-1.4

I have this save function, which overrides behaviour of the default save function:

```
class JobeetJob extends BaseJobeetJob {
    public function save(PropelPDO $con = null)
    {
        if($this->isNew() && !$this->getExpiresAt())
        {
            $now = $this->getCreatedAt() ? $this->getCreatedAt('U') : time();
            $this->setExpiresAt($now + 86400 * sfConfig::get('app_active_days'));
        }

        return parent::save($con);
    }
}
```

Took this from a book.

What bugs me is the meaning of the following line:

```
$now = $this->getCreatedAt() ? $this->getCreatedAt('U') : time();
```

How can getCreatedAt ever return true, if the 'if' before had isnew() check? Meaning that the object this refers to won't ever have the CreatedAt field filled, cause it's not in the database yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though `created_at` is set automatically, but you can also set it manually - even if an object is new.